# Scripting a deployment of an org-wide email address to a scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org

I'm setting up a CI/CD and currently I'm facing some challenges regarding  org wide verified emails and scratch orgs. Do you know if there is some workaround on this?
I can start to work on a script to change "on the fly" all the email alerts on flows to use the "current user" solution, but I'm a little bit short of time to do this from scratch.
Any advice would be appreciate.

Comment: Well, implement a whole framework just to change a string in the metadata files seems to be a bit excessive, but this could works for all unsupportive metadata, not just org wide emails. I'll give it a try to : https://github.com/davidbrowaeys/DXB